# How can I toggle or hide CSS pseudo-elements on event (e.g., click)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

***Background***

I have an HTML div which contains a ‘tooltip’-like feature (i.e., a text box pops up when a certain element is clicked or hovered over);  this tooltip has decorative pseudo-elements to make it look like a ‘speech bubble,’ added in css as `:before` and `:after` .

I have a JS script, which is intended to show and hide the tooltip and decoration, in response to click events (i.e., toggle them between ‘show’ and ‘hide’ states).

***Problem***

I can’t get the decorative pseudo-elements to hide when the tooltip is hidden; as pseudo-elements, they are not part of the DOM and so I can’t use normal selectors to manipulate them.

When the tooltip is hidden on click, the decorative pseudo-elements persist, which is not a usable result.

I can’t do away with the decorative elements, they are part of the work specification.

***Approach tried so far***

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin), my thought was to add an empty span with its own class, to which I’d prepend and append these pseudo-elements. Then, add or remove the class on click based on whether it exists already, or not.

I have also tried setting the class to which the pseudo-elements are pre/appended to display:none on click, but this also seems not to work

However, I cannot convince the pseudo-elements to hide on click.
I’ve included a screenshot of what these remnant pseudo-elements look like in the live environment.

Note: I tried to work up a running simulation for the purpose of this question, but I wasn’t able to and the original css file is massive; the code included below is for reference only.

All guidance is much appreciated!

```js
const barContainer = document.querySelector(".bar-container");
const decorationElement = document.querySelector("#decoration");

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  console.log('click event listener triggered');
  if (event.target.closest('.link') || event.target.classList.contains('link')) {
    if (barContainer.classList.contains('open')) {
      barContainer.classList.remove('open')
      decorationElement.classList.remove('decoration')
      document.querySelector('.tooltip-container').setAttribute('style', 'display:none');
    } else {
      barContainer.classList.add('open')
      decorationElement.classList.add('decoration')
      document.querySelector('.tooltip-container').setAttribute('style', 'display:block');
    }

  } else {
    barContainer.classList.remove('open')
    decorationElement.classList.remove('decoration')
    document.querySelector('.tooltip-container').setAttribute('style', 'display:none');
  }
});
```

```css
.foo-container {
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.bar-container {
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.bar-container:hover .tooltip-container,
.tooltip-container:hover,
.bar-container.open .tooltip-container {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 5%;
  border-radius: 4%;
  font-weight: 300;
  max-width: 90%;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 20px 0;
}


/*the below two rule sets create the rotated 'decoration' */

.bar-container:hover .tooltip-container:before,
.tooltip-container:hover:before,
.bar-container.open .tooltip-container:before,
.foo-container .bar-container:hover .decoration:before {
  content: "";
  width: 65px;
  height: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  z-index: 10;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 170px;
  background-color: white;
}

.foo-container .bar-container.open .decoration:before,
.foo-container .bar-container:hover .decoration:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #fff;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 2;
  top: -42px;
}


/* end 'deocration' */
```

```html
<div class="foo-container">
  <div class="bar-container">
    <p>text <span class='link'>the-link<span id='decoration' class='decoration'></span></span>
    </p>
    <div class='tooltip-container'>
      <p>lorem </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Screenshot of the undesirable 'persistent pseudo-elements' behavior** -->
[image: image of how persistent pseudo-elements appear after tooltip is closed]

Comment: I've converted your code to a snippet demo. Feel free to revise further. There's a link on the snippet in edit mode.

Comment: Using SVG for the tooltip is an option?